# Why does python say, "no module named os"?

Tags: python, operating-system

As usual, I opened Notepad++ and wrote my python code. Then when I opened my CMD to execute it, I got this error

```
`Fatal Python error: init_import_size: Failed to import the site module
Python runtime state: initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site.py", line 73, in <module>
    import os
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'os'
```

I uninstalled and reinstalled python hoping that it'll run, but it didn't. Can anybody please help!

EDIT: Python doesn't work on my pc. Whenever I type "python" in the CMD, it would throw this error, IDLE is also not opening. And yes, my python is added  to PATH so please don't say to add it to the path.

Comment: can you share the snippet code?

Comment: Do you have a file called `os.py`?

Comment: (Also, note that "OS" and "os" are different things. Your title doesn't match your question body. Please make sure to always copy error messages _exactly_. These differences can be important.)

Comment: The `os` module is part of your Python standard library and a [regular .py file](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/os.py), normally found in the same folder as `site.py`. If it is missing, your Python installation is hosed. Reinstall Python.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this snippet

```
import os
output = os.environ['HOME']
print(output)
```

If this is not working then there is issue with your python installation. You need to re-install it.

To get comfortable with python modules you can learn from [here](https://www.journaldev.com/14329/python-modules)

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work and I tried re installing it several times but no, I got no change.

Comment: Try to instal python using chocolaty package manager. It will set all the environment variable automatically.  https://medium.com/@JockDaRock/installing-the-chocolatey-package-manager-for-windows-3b1bdd0dbb49